# How to resolve 'CS7036' error when using AppUserManager class with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Error   CS7036
I am in the process of learning how to use Identity of .net MVC, and I need to create class "AppUserManager.cs" to manage users, and I have problem when system gives this error in my cs file and my software I can't function.

this is my AppUserManager.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
namespace MechIdentity.Models
{
    public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
    {
        public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store) : base(store) { }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc78r.png)
and here is the error message:

Error   CS7036
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'optionsAccessor' of 'UserManager.UserManager(IUserStore, IOptions, IPasswordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator>, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider, ILogger<UserManager>)

Comment: Your code sample and the contents of the picture look the same. Please remove the unnecessary picture link